# Can't create new project in QT Design Studio because of the extra large size of "Create New Project" dialogue Box. And also can not resize it

Tags: qt, new-project

I want to create a new project in the QT design studio. But whenever I click on the "create new project" button it opens an extra-large "New Project" titled dialogue box. Because of this, I can't reach the "Create" button, nor can I resize it.

How can I resize the window or reach the "create" button otherwise?
[image: Extra large "New Project" dialogue box]

Answer (score 0):

You could try using some Win key combinations to rearrange your window.

[image: Windows logo key shortcuts]

[Windows Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#WindowsVersion=Windows_10)